# Limit of $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If I have a sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, and I have defined the exact same sequence, just for it to start at $n=1$, which means $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$,

I have found the limit of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

My question: is there a theorem that shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Here are the sequences for reference:

$$ (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty} =\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_0=r & \\ 
a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n) & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$ (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} =\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_1=\cos(r) & \\ 
a_{n+1}=\cos(a_n) & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m quite sure that you could prove that theorem easily!

Comment: Thank you math and Martin! I do not know what a tail means in a sequence. I have proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n+k}$, is that have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition**

Given a metric space $(X,d_{X})$ and a sequence $a_{n}\in X$, we say that $b_{n}$ is a subsequence of $a_{n}$ if there exists a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $b_{n} = a_{f(n)}$.

**Proposition**

Given a sequence $a_{n}\in X$ on the metric space $(X,d_{X})$, it converges to $L$ if, and only if, every subsequence converges to the same value.

**Proof**

Based on such definition, we can prove the desired claim.

Indeed, if every subsequence of $a_{n}$ converges to $L$, then $a_{n}$ converges to $L$: it suffices to take $f(n) = n$.

Conversely, suppose that $a_{n}$ converges to $L$. Let $b_{n} = a_{f(n)}$ be one of its subsequences.

According to the the definition of convergence, let $\varepsilon > 0$.

Then there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
n \geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{X}(a_{n},L) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since $f(n) \geq n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
f(n) \geq n \geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{X}(a_{f(n)},L) = d_{X}(b_{n},L) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $b_{n}$ converges to $L$, and we are done.

**Solution**

At your case, it suffices to take $f(n) = n+1$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I do not know what a metric space is, but I will look into that. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome ! You can take $X = \mathbb{R}$ if you want, where $d_{X}(a,b) = |a - b|$.

Comment: Oh I see, $dx$ is for an integral?

Comment: Here $d_{X}$ represents the metric corresponding to the set $X$.